# Changed /etc/passwd, now I can't log in, what's the best way to recover it (headless)?

Tags: password

I made the mistake of changing of the `pi` user name string to something else (e.g. `foo`) in `/etc/passwd`. I did not change the home directory. Now when I try to log in via ssh to the new user, sshd immediately closes the connection (I have my ssh public key in `/home/pi/.ssh/autorized_keys`). If I try to log in as `pi`, it asks for a password, but then fails to authenticate.

I can easily modify the boot partition (it mounts on macOS). Is there any way to set things up so I can log in, perhaps via serial console, to fix `/etc/passwd`? Or is my only hope to mount the entire filesystem (e.g. on a Debian VM) and edit `/etc/passwd`?

### Update

I was able to mount the boot drive on a Debian VM and edit `/etc/passwd` to restore the username to `pi`, but any attempt to connect `ssh pi@<ip address>` is immediately refused. And the device no longer seems to advertise its mDNS name. The Docker containers are running, though. I’m very confused.

Comment: Why would someone downvote this question? It's a perfectly valid question, even if it does describe a mistake. There was a time when unix would have perfectly accepted this change.

Comment: probably because the question is not about Raspberry Pi, but about Linux ... it does not belong here

Comment: That seems like splitting hairs, but okay, I'll go elsewhere.

Comment: @Rick sorry that you experience this. I can second, this stackexchange is very unfriendly with a lot of unwanted gate keeping, there are much more positive communities (e.g. tex.stackexchange is amazing). I recommend to use forums instead.

Comment: @0__ Yeah, I’ve never experienced this on other SE sites, and as a professional software engineer, I use them frequently.

Comment: You need to edit `/etc/shadow`.

Comment: For anyone who reads this question, know that changing a user name by editing `/etc/passwd` is not the best way to accomplish this. Instead, read up on the `usermod` command.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to SSH in remotely, could you try connecting a keyboard and monitor temporarily to the raspi and log in locally?

Comment: No, not really, I don't have a monitor or keyboard handy, just a laptop and serial cable. That's why I'm looking for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to see what you hoped to achieve by changing the pi user name string (this is a totally new way to screw up your OS).

You can remove the password by changing `pi:x:1000:1000:` to `pi::1000:1000:`
This is simple with a monitor/keyboard.

Whether this will work over `ssh` is unknown.

Normally logging in as a root shell is the way to fix problems but this requires a monitor/keyboard as `ssh` root access is prohibited.

Frankly the best way is to **restore from your backup**.

Comment: I had hoped to achieve changing the name of the user without first creating another user just to allow usermod to function. This was once a perfectly reasonable way to change a username.